# How to search single word in the jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery

How to search a word in the jquery autocomplete? Consider i'm have an array as below. if i'm typing like 'S' then i have to print all 'S' related result like  ActionScript , AppleScript,Scala,BASIC,Haskell, Scheme,ColdFusion etc.. You can update this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/Lkk4pd9o/)

```
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v03pjhqk/1/ - sees fine what are you really looking for... the dropdown menu has all the items with `s` in it

Comment: I think your fiddle works as per your requirement!! what's the problem here??

Comment: Try separating `js` from `html` at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lkk4pd9o/1/

Comment: may be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v03pjhqk/2/ - which allows to select multiple items

Comment: :) No what i'm looking for is when i type "S" or "a"  then it have to print related search may be in console.log .

Comment: also i want to disable the drop down, "disabled:true"

Comment: if i type "S" and press enter key. Then it have to print related search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.
You don't need auto complete at all.

```js
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

$("#tags").keyup(function(){
    $("#found").find('p').remove();
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.length>0){
    for(var i=0;i<availableTags.length;i++)
    {
        var item =   availableTags[i];
        if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase())>-1)
        {
            $("#found").append("<p>"+item+"<br></p>");
        }
    }
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
      <div id="found"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the dropdown, maybe you don't even need jquery UI. You could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkk4pd9o/3/):

```
$input.on('keyup', function(){
    availableTags.filter(function(_item){
        return _item.toLowerCase().indexOf($inp.val()) > -1;
    }).forEach(function(_item) {
        console.log( _item );
    });
});
```